# Getting 'Invalid token request' in Jmeter even though I have provided the correct data and response

Tags: jmeter

Response body I am getting:

```json
{"status":401,"message":"Invalid token","messageCode":null,"returnObject":null,"count":0}
```

Request header which I am sending:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Bearer ${Token}
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
uuid: ${uuid}
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Host: platform.wealthobjectsworld.com
```

I have to pass the authorization bearer token but I am not able to do so still getting the request header as `Authorization: Bearer ${Token}` It should go like `Authorization: Bearer Token`

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending the header value as `Bearer ${Token}` and the `${Token}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) placeholder isn't getting substituted with the respective value of this variable it means that the logic of setting the variable value fails somewhere somehow.

First of all check whether the variable exists after you've just set it, you can do it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)

Depending on the outcome you will either need to properly configure the [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) which extracts the token and stores it into the variable or make sure that the value is not overwritten somewhere else due to i.e. wrong [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) of the Post-Processor .